# How can I access variables which defined in my view code in Sass file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I want to write some code in my rails view page to define a class with param for a div, which is like:

```
%div{:class => div_with_width("500px")}
```

then in sass file, define a class mixin like:

```
=div_with_width(!width)
  div
    :width = !width
```

Can I write such code? Or is there a good way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, by definition mixins are intended to be used in other SASS files. You *may* have to simply use the mixin in another SASS file, applying it to a real class. As SASS files are compiled to CSS if you don't go this route you may never see the mixin used and thus not defined at all in your final CSS output.

Comment: Yes, you are right, jaydel. I am using mixins in my project like what you said. But do you know is there a better way to solve my question?

Comment: I mean, how to make sass can access variables defined in rails view file?

Comment: honestly I don't know of a way to do this. The SASS files are compiled down to actual CSS before being used by Rails (as you already know, I'm sure) so the variables don't even exist by the time the style definitions even make it to the views.

Comment: Jaydel, thanks for your explain! I'm afraid I have to find another solution to make it work.